# async def on_message(message, ctx)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a channel on my discord server named #pay-respecc. The goal here is to allow people to pay their respeccs without troublemakers abusing the system. I tried to make it so if you sent something in the channel that isn't "f", it gets deleted and the bot dms you a warning. Although it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? The error is `TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx`.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message, ctx):
    if message.content != "f" and message.channel.id == 699364974014890044:
        await message.delete()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Paying respeccs',
            description = 'Please do not abuse your ability to pay respeccs. To pay respecc the correct way, please send `f`. Any other message will be deleted and reviewed by the staff team in the case of offendable messages.',
            color = discord.Color.from_rgb(r=159, g=255, b=255)
        )
        embed.set_footer(text='{}' .format(ctx.author))
        await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
        print(f"Deleted '{message.content}' on channel #payrespecc by {message.author}. Warning message has been sent!")
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

`on_message()` does not receive `ctx`, only `message`.
See https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214639/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-async-def-on-messagemessage-ctx).